# Retrieve XML Node With Specific Value In downloadURL

Tags: php, javascript, xml, google-maps-api-3

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please. Firstly, my apologies as to some this be a very basic question, I'm very new to working with XML so please bear with me.

I'm using this section of code to successfully load marker data from a MySQL database, placing them on a Google map.

```
            downloadUrl("loadallmyfinds.php", function(data) {  
            var xml = parseXml(data);
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { 
            // obtain the attribues of each marker 
            var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("findosgb36lat")); 
            var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("findosgb36lon")); 
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng); 
            var locationname = markers[i].getAttribute("locationname"); 
            var finddescription = markers[i].getAttribute("finddescription"); 
            var html = "<b>" + 'Description: ' + "</b>" + finddescription; 
            var findcategory = markers[i].getAttribute("findcategory"); 
            // create the marker 
            var marker = createMarker(point,html,locationname,finddescription,findcategory);
            }
```

**XML Output**

```
<markers>
<marker userid="27" findid="1" locationname="Test Location 1" findosgb36lat="53.0000" findosgb36lon="-1.00000" osgridref="" dateoftrip="21/06/2012" findcategory="Artefact" finddescription="A rare Roman vase."/>
</markers>
```

The problem I have, is that in it's current state all records are being retrieved irrespective of the user, but I need to make this user specific, to be more precise, if the `userid` element value matches the variable I have on my form which is `$idnum`.

I thought that I may be able to do this via the PHP query that is being loaded in the above i.e. `loadallmyfinds` using a `GET` clause, but sadly this doesn't work.

I've done some research into this and I believe, from my limited knowledge, that I may be able to this via XML, but I'm really not sure how to implement it.

i just wondered whether someone could possibly look at this please and offer some guidance on how I may go about it so the records are filtered.

Many thanks and kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the user id in the as `$idnum`. So, please change your ajax request from this:

`downloadUrl("loadallmyfinds.php", function(data) {`

to this:

`downloadUrl("loadallmyfinds.php?id=<?php echo $idnum?>", function(data) {`

and in the `loadallmyfinds.php` file:

**OLD COMMENT**

I guess you can store the userid in your session (`$_SESSION['uid']=$userId;`)

...and in your `loadallmyfinds.php` file, read this session variable and return only that user related content.

Comment: Hi @Pushpesh, thank you for replying to my post. Unfortunately I'm unable to incorporate a session start into my code because I'm using a piece of software that handles the `membership` types using `Session` variables. As I said I think that the best way to do this would be via the XML route. kind regards

Comment: Ok, as far as i understand, `loadallmyfinds.php` return an XML for all users and you want to restrict it to a particular user at a time, right? Let me know and we can work towards a solution.

Comment: Hi @Pushpesh, thank you very much for your continued help with this. Yes basically `loadallmyfinds.php` pulls the data from a MySQL database. The PHP script is then parsed via XML, and you are correct in assuming that I only want the records for the current user returned. I've added a sample of the XML output to my original post which may help. Kind regards

Comment: Hmm, so as you have said, you have the user's id in the form `$idnum`..try passing that to your ajax request. Please see my modified response.

Comment: Hi, thank you for this. Could I just run past you what I've done please, because the PHP script doesn't return any markers. In my main script I've used this: `downloadUrl("loadallmyfinds.php?userid=<?php echo $idnum?>", function(data) {`, 
Then in my `loadallmyfinds.php` script I've used this: `$_SESSION['userid']=$userid;` and in the query itself I've added this to the end `finds.userid='$userid'`. If I've done this correctly, unfortunately it doesn't work and the marker isn't populated on the map. I've checked JS Console and there are no errors being created. Kind regards

Comment: Hi, still there...yes, there are errors with the way you did it. Let's talk when you are online.

Comment: Hi @Pushpesh, I suspect you're very busy, but I'm online now and if its' convenient with you it would be great to talk through this. Thank you once again for all your help. Kind regards

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12740/discussion-between-pushpesh-and-irhm)